# Show that if the intersection is non-empty, then the union is connected of the following

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a family of connected subsets of a metric space $X$ ($I$ is some set of indices). Show that if the intersection $\bigcap A_i \neq \emptyset$ , then $\bigcup A_i$ is connected.

Comment: Sorry. Don't know how to write math characters on here.

Comment: There’s a tutorial and quick reference [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for writing mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\bigcap A_i \ne \emptyset$, let $x \in \bigcap A_i$. Now if $U$ and $V$ are non-empty disjoint open sets separating $\bigcup A_i$ then $x \in U$ or $x \in V$. Without loss of generality, suppose $x \in U$. Now, where does $x$ come from and what can we say about it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "separating the union of A_i"

Comment: Meaning $ A = U\cup V $.

Comment: I guess you could say x comes from the intersection of A_i but is not an element of V

Comment: But that must be a contradiction... do you see why?

Comment: because it's the intersection? so it must be both?